# Why is one of the conditions of a vector space that if I add two vectors, the sum must be within the space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have been working with vector spaces for a while and I now take for granted what the vector space does. I feel like I dont really understand why multiplication and addition must be defined on a vector space. For example, it feels like adding two vectors and having their sum contained within the space is just a name for a vector space and I dont get what necessarily happens IF the two vector's sum arent in the space. In other words, I dont know why must addition and multiplication must be defined on a vector space, is it to take advantage of nice properties? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector space is a generalisation of the 3D space we live in and the behaviour of vector addition and scalar multiplication is modelled on that.

Another consideration is that mathematical structures are generally *closed* - groups, rings, fields, vector spaces are all closed. This means that the operations that can be performed on elements of the structure result in another element of the structure. I can't think of a mathematical structure that is not closed in this way. The reason for defining structures in this way is clear, if a structure were not closed then the results of some operations being outside the structure would be undefined in terms of the rules of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the plane $\mathbb R^2$ as a vector space. Now truncate it on all sides so you are just left with a little rectangle about the origin. Now, you this is your world and you take two vectors in it and add them, you may land inside the rectangle or you may not. You don't want to have to worry about such issues, and thus simply make the assumption that your vector space is not truncated. That you can always add vectors and stay firmly in the space. Same goes for scalar product.

Comment: "Scalar product" may be confusing here. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of "natural" spaces that happen to satisfy the properties of a vector space.  For example $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C(\mathbb{R})$.  Spaces with this kind of addition and scalar multiplication come up so much that we came up with the abstract definition of a vector space.  That way we can just do one proof using abstract vector spaces and be able to apply that to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $C(\mathbb{R})$.  Sometimes we are also interested in topology of a particular space, and for that we use the theory of topological vector spaces/Banach spaces.  So my point is, a vector space has addition and multiplication because those are the things that we are actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The sum and multiplication of two vectors $u,v$ from a linear space $V$ has to belong to $V$ because we want to consider elements that share some common properties, in particular they all can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors that form any base of $V$.

It is the same as in case of groups. In example we can express $V$ as a quotient set: a set of equivalence classes. $u+v$ has to belong to some equivalence class.

Answer (score 1):

To see why this property is important, consider an example where the property fails. Let $X$ be the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in the Cartesian plane, so 
$$X = \{(x,0) \, | \, x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(0,y) \, | \, y \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
Is $X$ a vector space? If not, what axiom fails? And (perhaps of more importance to extending your understanding of vector spaces) what part of your intuition for vector spaces does this example effect?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the calculus problems we can solve are linear.  For these problems, if we know two solutions, then the sum is another solution.  So is a scalar multiple of either.  So the set of solutions to a large set of problems is a vector space.  It makes sense to understand vector spaces.

Many things aren't vector spaces : if you take two vectors on the surface of a sphere, their sum is usually not on the sphere.